# F# Data: JSON Parser. Using JsonExtensions

Tags: f#, f#-3.0, f#-data

It is my first question on SO...so do not judge strictly =)

Usually all my questions techout in [chat rooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f) (believe me, a lot of them =)).

Recently, we are talking about the [RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/). And I wondered to complement some of the tasks code to F#

One of them is [JSON](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/JSON).

One of the possible solutions is the use of "F# Data: JSON Parser". So my question is linked with it.

This code works well:

```
open FSharp.Data
open FSharp.Data.JsonExtensions

type Person = {ID: int; Name:string}

let json = """[ { "ID": 1, "Name": "First"  }, { "ID": 2, "Name": "Second" }]"""
json |> printfn "%s"

match JsonValue.Parse(json) with
| JsonValue.Array(x) ->
    x |> Array.map(fun x -> {ID = System.Int32.Parse((x?ID).ToString()); Name = (string x?Name)})
| _ -> failwith "fail json"
|> Array.iter(fun x -> printfn "%i  %s" x.ID x.Name)
```

Print:

```
[ { "ID": 1, "Name": "First"  }, { "ID": 2, "Name": "Second" }]
1  "First"
2  "Second"
```

But it

```
{ID = System.Int32.Parse((x?ID).ToString()); Name = (string x?Name)}
```

doesn't look good.

[This](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonValue.html) I read about JsonExtensions,

but when I use

```
{ID = (x?ID.AsInteger()) ; Name = (x?Name.AsString()) }
```

I get compile errors:

- The field, constructor or "AsInteger" is not defined
- The field, constructor or "AsString" is not defined

Strangely, thing is that I see accessibility through "open FSharp.Data.JsonExtensions"

[image]

So, question: How to use JsonExtensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to reproduce this using a minimal example, but I do not get the error - can you try the following minimal sample?

```
#r "...../FSharp.Data.dll"
open FSharp.Data.JsonExtensions
open FSharp.Data

JsonValue.Parse("A").AsArray()
|> Array.map (fun a -> a?ID.AsInteger())
```

I do not get auto-completion on `a?ID.` (which is a limitation of the editor), but it compiles fine.

The only reason why I think this could be not working is if you had another `open` declaration that would import another implementation of the `?` operator that is not returning `JsonValue`.

The `JsonValue` API is certainly not as nice as just using the type provider - so if you can, I'd probably go for the type provider instead (the low-level API is good if you need to iterate over everything in JSON recursively).

Comment: This is very confusing. What version of F# + VS are you using?

Comment: (They are C#-style extension methods and so I think this won't work in VS 2012)

Comment: Yes, I have VS12. Could you explain why it does not work for this version?

Comment: Ah, that explains things. All of [those methods](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/blob/master/src/Json/JsonExtensions.fs#L75) are written using the `Extension` attribute. Consuming those is only supported in F# that comes with VS 2013 - previous versions of F# did not support C#-style extension methods.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.