# F# JsonValue example doesn't work

Tags: json, f#

In [F# Data: JSON Parser](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonValue.html)

There is an example showing how to extract data:

```
let info =
  JsonValue.Parse(""" 
    { "name": "Tomas", "born": 1985,
      "siblings": [ "Jan", "Alexander" ] } """)
open FSharp.Data.JsonExtensions

// Print name and birth year
let n = info?name
printfn "%s (%d)" (info?name.AsString()) (info?born.AsInteger())

// Print names of all siblings
for sib in info?siblings do
  printfn "%s" (sib.AsString())
```

I copied and pasted this code to try it out, but it won't compile,  I get the error:

> Error 53  The field, constructor or member 'AsString' is not defined

Is there something missing in the example code?

Comment: Which F# do you have?

Comment: Do you use VisualStudio 2015 or something older?

Comment: I'm running Visual Studio 2012 (no room to install 2015/17)

Comment: then it's impossible. I posted the same Q earlier

Comment: Possible duplicate of [F# Data: JSON Parser. Using JsonExtensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33056348/f-data-json-parser-using-jsonextensions)

Comment: Thanks!  I can stop beating my head against the wall!!

Answer (score 1):

This can't work with VS 2012 because it lacks the ability to handle extensions for F#